# In the new version of Windows 7 MovieMaker, where is the (1) cutter, (2) timeline, and (3) fade?

Tags: windows-movie-maker

I have **Windows 7** and wanted to make a quick movie with Movie Maker but apparently in the **new version of MovieMaker** they changed the interface to the Office 2007 **Ribbon** and now I can't find the functionality I used to use:

All I want to do is:

- cut the two videos so I get the pieces I want
- drag those pieces down into the time line
- drag one video over the other so that it fades into it

But the **"cutter" icon** is gone and the **timeline** at the bottom is gone. And under animations there seems to be new animations but I don't find **fade**.

**How can I get the cutter icon, the timeline, and the fade animation to appear again or what's the new paradigm I don't understand?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the clip you want to cut. Under the '*video tools*' that appears is a '*trim tool*' that allows you to select the part you want. Don't forget to '*save trim*'.

The fade is hiding in the '*animations*' tab under '*transitions*' and is called '*cross fade*'. Select the clip you want to fade into, go to the animations tab and expand the transitions list. cross fade is fairly close to the top.

good luck

Comment: thanks, that's getting me there, I don't understand when I am "on the fade" so I can, e.g. delete it and add a new one or define it's duration. Is there a way as in the old version to drag a video onto the other one so that you can control visually when the fade starts and stops?

Comment: so now I have two videos, when it I click on one, it shows it has a pixelate animation of 2 seconds, and when I click on the second video it shows it has a crossfade animation of 1 second, but when I play the videos, there is no fade :-(

Comment: I don't know about the dragging but I can't find it either :-(
But the transitions just work for me so I'm afraid I can't help you any further there :-(

Comment: I had to add a black .png at the end and crossfade into it to get it to fade out, ok, slowly getting it, thanks.